# CodeIgniter - Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() - Driver seems to be loaded (PHP Version: 8.0.3)

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, sqlsrv

I have to create a project for my company which needs to be connected to a Microsoft SQL Server. I followed the instructions to install the driver for the server on my webserver. If I run `phpinfo();` or `print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());` I get `sqlsrv` as a result.

The problem is if I try to connect to the database server via CodeIgniter, I get the error message

> Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()`

But if I try to connect to the server via `new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=" . $this->_serverName . ";Database=" . $this->_database, $this->_uid, $this->_pwd);`, it works totally fine.

That's my database.php from CodeIgniter:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'jderigs',
    'password' => 'Mumsili1',
    'database' => 'chs_001',
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

That's the result of `print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => mysql
    [1] => sqlite
    [2] => sqlsrv
)
```

I have absolutely no idea what I did wrong. Hopefully someone of you can help me.

Comment: What exactly is the result from the `phpinfo()` call? You must see two sections in the ouptut: `pdo_sqlsrv` and `sqlsrv`. Functions `sqlsrv_*` are from the `sqlsrv` part of the driver.

Comment: There's just a section with the name `pdo_sqlsrv`. If I understand you correct the section `sqlsrv` is missing, so I did something wrong while configure it, right?

Comment: Yes, you need to [install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/loading-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-ver15) this part as a PHP extension.

Comment: I already did, but I think I made a mistake somewhere. I'll try it again.

Comment: Okay, I made a mistake while installing the driver and I didn't know that there has to be a section named `sqlsrv`, but it's working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a friendly user I found out that I made a mistake while configuring the webserver. I didn't know that there has to be a section with the name `sqlsrv`.

Reinstalled the driver and now everything works fine.