# Codeigniter 4 - cron job with CI4 controller and Database connection

Tags: database, codeigniter, cron, command-line-interface, sqlsrv

I'm trying to execute a cron job with CI4 controller that check for a certain value in a database.
I've tried several methods but every time I get this error:

> [CodeIgniter\Database\Exceptions\DatabaseException]
>
> Unable to connect to the database. Main connection [SQLSRV]: Call to
> undefined function CodeIgniter\Database\SQLSRV\sqlsrv_configure()
>
> at SYSTEMPATH\Database\BaseConnection.php:400

Is there something i'm missing ?

I'd like to define a cron jpb in windows that calls that controller every 15 minutes and check for a certain data in my database.

DB is welll configured and extensions are installed. DB is working properly in the application, i got the error only when i try to call the controller as a CLI. Here is my db config:

DB config is:

public $defaultGroup = 'default';

```
/**
 * The default database connection.
 *
 * @var array
 */
public $default = [
    'DSN'      => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'myuser',
    'password' => 'mypassword',
    'database' => 'dbtest',
    'DBDriver' => 'SQLSRV',
    'DBPrefix' => '',
    'pConnect' => false,
    'DBDebug'  => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'DBCollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swapPre'  => '',
    'encrypt'  => false,
    'compress' => false,
    'strictOn' => false,
    'failover' => [],
    'port'     => 1433,
];
```

Comment: which CI.x version are you using?, also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66760840/codeigniter-call-to-undefined-function-sqlsrv-connect-driver-seems-to-be-l and this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398029/codeigniter-mssql-sqlsrv-connection

Comment: As well as: *do you have the sqlsrv extension installed*? it would help to see your config database file setup.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, CI is 4.1.4 with PHP 7.4.
SQL drivers are installed and working properly when i use the application, i got this error only when i try to call the controller in CLI mode.

Comment: Use the command feature from CI4 for your case.